# banner set interval

Tags: ads

I have designed a simple jquery banner for one website.  The banner is working fine but how to refresh the banner with set interval. I have gone through various codes but it is not working. Please do help me by correcting the code repetition of the banner for a specific intervals.

THE CSS CODE:

```
 .banner {-webkit-border-radius:6px;    -moz-border-radius:8px;    border-radius:8px; 
          -khtml-border-radius: 8px; border:#bbd9ef solid 1px; background:#f5fffa; 
          padding: 5px 0 0 20px; width: 200px; height: 110px; 
         }
  .k, .l, .m, .n {position: relative; top: -200px; text-decoration: none; }
  .n { font-weight: bold; color: red; }
```

THE SCRIPT CODE with jquery1.9.1:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".banner a").hide();
           (function() {
             $(".k").show().animate({top: "0"}, 3000, function() {
                $(".l").show().animate({top: "0"},3000, function(){
                $(".m").show().animate({top: "0"},3000, function(){
                  $(".n").show().animate({top: "0"},3000);
                  });
                });
            });
          })();
         });
```

THE HTML CODE:

```
<div class="banner">
    <a href="#" class="k">Design banner in your ownway</a><br />
    <a href="#" class="l"> Get more taffic and publishers.</a><br/>
    <a href="#" class="m">Still doubt, please do contact:</a><br/><br/>
    <a href="#" class="n">www.freemenu.info</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a jsfiddle for the question: http://jsfiddle.net/f2JCV/

Answer (score 1):

Use `setInterval` like this: http://jsfiddle.net/f2JCV/1/

`setInterval` will not execute immediately. It waits for a timeout before it begins, so I wrote a helper function to call it immediately.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Call the fn immediately, then every interval milliseconds
    function setIntervalNow(fn,interval) {
        fn();
        return setInterval(fn, interval);
    }

    setIntervalNow(function() {
        $(".banner a").hide().css('top',-200); // reset the items to the top
           (function() {
             $(".k").show().animate({top: "0"}, 3000, function() {
                $(".l").show().animate({top: "0"},3000, function(){
                $(".m").show().animate({top: "0"},3000, function(){
                  $(".n").show().animate({top: "0"},3000);
                  });
                });
            });
          })();
    }, 15000); // repeat every 15 seconds
});
```

Comment: The asker didn't say he needed it to execute immediately, did he? Why go through the trouble in this case? Irregardless, I really like the setIntervalNow function. It reminds me of a do/while loop except with the built-in delay. Cool example of extending JavaScript! +1

Comment: Actually, yes, he did. The example he gave executes immediately.